# Dynamic boolean join in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframe with same schema as below -

df_source:

```
id, name, age
```

df_target:

```
id,name,age
```

**"id" is primary column in both the tables and rest are attribute columns**

i am accepting primary and attribute column list from user as below-

```
primary_columns = ["id"]
attribute_columns = ["name","age"]
```

I need to join above two dataframes dynamically as below -

```
df_update = df_source.join(df_target, (df_source["id"] == df_target["id"]) & ((df_source["name"] != df_target["name"]) | (df_source["age"] != df_target["age"]))  ,how="inner").select([df_source[col] for col in df_source.columns])
```

how can i achieve this join condition dynamically in pyspark since number of attribute and primary key columns can change as per the user input? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you just can achieve the desired output using an inner join on the `primary_columns` and a `where` clause that loops over the `attribute_columns`.

Since the two DataFrames have the same column names, use [`alias`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias) to differentiate column names after the `join`.

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_update = df_source.alias("s")\
    .join(df_target.alias("t"), on=primary_columns, how="inner")\
    .where(
         reduce(
             lambda a, b: a|b, 
             [(col("s."+c) != col("t."+c) for c in attribute_columns]
         )\
    )
    .select("s.*")
```

Use reduce to apply the bitwise OR operation on the columns in `attribute_columns`.